# REGEX to remove local anchor tags

Tags: php, html, regex

I need some help writing a regular expression pattern in PHP. I need to take a string containing HTML, find all anchor tags that contain a LOCAL href and remove the tags, while keeping the text within the tag.

Example:

```
<a href="/link1.html">Link 1</a> 
<a href="../link2.html">Link 2</a>
<a href="http://www.localdomain.com/link3.html">Link 3</a>
```

should become:

```
Link 1
Link 2
Link 3
```

EDIT:
I'm looking for something like this:

```
function remove_internal_links($content) {
  $pattern = '/<a href="([^"])/';
  $content = preg_replace($pattern, '\\1', $content);
}
```

Where I need help (obviously) is with the $pattern.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem. In addition, please take the time to share the steps you've taken so far to research or resolve things on your own.

Comment: [The Pony, he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Is it an option to use a third part library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some third part library to parse the html like [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       if($element->href ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could either extract the part you want by:

```
>[^<]*
```

or replace  the things you don't want with "" by:

replaceAll

```
<[^>]*>
```